# Alternative notation for direct sum: $E^{(I)}$

Tags: notation, modules, direct-sum

Bourbaki's *Algebra* (1998), Ch. II §1.7, introduces the following notation for a specific type of direct sum:

> When all the $E_i$ are equal to the same $A$-module $E$, the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i\in I} E_i$ is also denoted $E^{(I)}$: its elements are the mappings of $I$ into $E$ with finite support.

Now, I understand the motivation behind this notation: $E^I = \{ f : I \to E \}$, so $$E^{(I)} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{ f:I\to E \mid \operatorname{supp}(f)<\infty \}$$ seems reasonable (in fact, if $I$ is finite, the two sets are of course equal to each other).

Bourbaki also uses this notation to then write e.g. $$E^{(A\times B)} = \text{set of formal (finite) linear combinations of elements }(a,b).$$

**The question:** I have the feeling this $E^{(I)}$ notation might conflict with other notations, or also that maybe no one besides Bourbaki uses it anymore.

Some quick advice (authors that use it, other uses of the notation, personal recommendations, etc.) would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I also use it, and a lot of mathematicians that I know use it. I don't see what it might conflict with. Actually, it is a quite standard notation.

Comment: For one, Aiyah and MacDonald mention and use it in their *Introduction to commutative algebra*. I'm ok with it and I use it whenever I want to indicate the set of functions such that et cetera. I also enjoy notations like $E^{\oplus I}=\bigoplus_I E$, $E^{\otimes I}=\bigotimes_I E$, $E^{\wedge I}=\bigwedge^I E$... What I think to be the main issue of $E^{(I)}$ is not with the notation but with the fact that I feel as if it indicates a set, and not quite a set with structure (in this case, the morphisms from the components to it). But then, notations which may covey this fail to be concise.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thank you for the explicit examples. I agree that the notation is non-ideal in terms of making it clear that it's a module (or, I suppose, a vector space), not just a set. But I feel like the (I think almost universally accepted) $Y^X$ notation has the same problem, right?

Comment: @BlondCafé I'm not referring to the module structure (which is standard), I'm referring to the structure of coproduct in the category of modules, i.e. to the fact that the direct sum of the family $(M_i)_{i\in I}$ is given by the module $\bigoplus_{i\in I} M_i$ *and* by the injections $\iota_i:M_i\to \bigoplus_{i\in I}M_i$ where $\iota_i(m)$ is the sequence $(\iota_i(m))_j=\begin{cases} m&\text{if }j=i\\ 0&\text{if }j\ne i\end{cases}$. This gets partially lost in many short notations (sometimes rightly so), but sometimes it plays a role. I agree that a similar thing happens with products.

Answer (score 1):

There are some people who use it often, and some people who wouldn't know what that means. I use this notation myself, but I usually (depending on audience) also say what it means the first time I use it.

If you want something almost universally understood without needing any explanation, I think $E^{\oplus I}$ or $\bigoplus_I E$ is a good choice.